How can we run another process(MSI) with elevated access inside the primary installer(MSI)after the InstallFinalize action in silent Mode (Wix)
Reading the Wix help I see that "Deferred execution custom actions must come after InstallInitialize and come before InstallFinalize in the action sequence."
Well, I need to run an msi and exe in silent with elevated access after the completion of the current MSI installer.So what I've tried is on below,
During Silent Mode:

Added a Custom Action(SilentLaunchSecApp) with deferred execute
before InstallFinalize

Action SilentLaunchSecApp will try to launch the process(another
msi) in silent mode


Error : Another Installation is in progress. You must complete that installation before continuing this one.
To overcome this Error ,

Added the custom action with immediate execute after InstallFinalize
and this is not allowing the process to run in elevated mode.

While executing in silent mode , the UAC prompt is not allowed to
trigger hence its will try to run the process and exited with error
says "Ensure that the process running the MSI installer has
sufficient permissions"



This would be something a bundle exe does including pre and post checks and the ability to update, repair, uninstall both msi.
